# Get integer number in interval with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to know which is the best method to get the integer/whole number in interval with native JavaScript function?

for example if I have [1.3, 2.5] ==> given result: 2

Comment: so are you looking for the average of two numbers and round this to the nearest whole number?

Comment: If you have a and b, `Math.round((a+b)/2)` should do.

Comment: No, i am asking for the whole number in the interval . I always have only one whole nomber wetwen the 2 extreme [x,y]

Comment: [(log(x)/log(3))+1 , (log(x)/log(3))] here is the interval that i use.

Comment: Then you know it's the number after (log(x)/log(3))+1, right? So Math.ceil((log(x)/log(3))+1) is enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the integer value from the left value and the ceiled value from the right value and get the integer value from the middled value.

```js
function middleInt(interval) {
    return Math.floor((Math.floor(interval[0]) + Math.ceil(interval[1])) / 2);
}

console.log(middleInt([1.3, 2.5]));
console.log(middleInt([1.3, 1.8]));
```